# Not able to install argon2 in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, django

Argon2 lib is not getting installed in windows 10. I'm getting the following error:

```
pip3 install argon2
 Running setup.py install for argon2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   package init file 'phc-winner-argon2\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file).
```

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools as well. And using Python 3.9.1

Comment: Got same issue. Sadly it seems there is no answer forthcoming from here.